# How can I loop pxcor in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I am a novice. How can I loop this for values of pxcor from 99 to 1?

```
ask patches
[ if chemicalR <= chemicalW and abs pycor < 1 and pxcor = 99
  [sprout-red-cells 1]
]
ask red-cells
[ set color red
  set size 1
  set shape "circle"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `loop` command in NetLogo. But looking at your code, I suspect you actually want to have every patch that meets certain conditions sprout a single red ball. If so, it is much more direct (and more NetLogo-y) to do this with a patchset.

```
ask patches with [chemicalR <= chemicalW and abs pycor < 1 and pxcor >= 1 and pxcor <= 99]
[ sprout-red-cells 1
  [ set color red
    set size 1
    set shape "circle"
  ]
]
```

I have also moved the commands for the new red-cells to happen as the red-cell is created.

If this doesn't do what you're trying to do, can you give a bit more detail about what you're trying to achieve?